Remove Comma From Each Line
I was able to format the json data as I expected and here's the code snippet that I tried so far:
const data = [
  {
    "id": 654298,
    "included": [
      {
        "id": 654298,
        "levelColumn": "DIM4_COL5",
        "levelColumnName": "Region",
        "isIncluded": true,
        "tabs": [
          {
            "tabId": 640111,
            "tabName": "Growth"
          },
          {
            "tabId": 640031,
            "tabName": "Direct Sales"
          },
          {
            "tabId": 640021,
            "tabName": "Operator Review"
          }
        ],
        "levels": [
          {
            "permValue": "WEST FS",
            "permName": "WEST FS"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "excluded": []
  }
];

var formatted = "Included \n"  + 
data.map(c => c.included.map(d => `\nFor Level ` 
+ d.levelColumnName 
+ `\nTabs ${d.tabs.map(e => `\n- ` 
+ e.tabName.toString().split(",").join("\n \n"))}\n` + 
`\nPermissions ${d.levels.map(e => `\n- ` 
+ e.permName.toString().split(",").join("\n \n"))}\n` ));

console.log(formatted);

There could be place for improvement, but for now this is what I got.
The Output I get now:
Included 

For Level Region
Tabs 
- Growth,
- Direct Sales,
- Operator Review

Permissions 
- WEST FS

Pretty much what I was expecting. Somehow I am not able to remove the comma from each line of the Tabs grouping. Seems like if Permissions grouping had multiple values too, it would also have trailing commas.
I was hoping split(",").join("\n \n") would eliminate that, but that didn't work out. Any way to remove the trailing commas?

Since this is JSON it would proably be smarter and easier to just parse it and then loop through the objects writing away the output?

as @somethinghere said, in my opinion your code doesn't make any sense... parsing json manually? why??

.join can be used at the end of arrays to avoid the commas :


const data = [ { "id": 654298, "included": [ { "id": 654298, "levelColumn": 
  "DIM4_COL5", "levelColumnName": "Region", "isIncluded": true, "tabs": [ { 
  "tabId": 640111, "tabName": "Growth" }, { "tabId": 640031, "tabName": 
  "Direct Sales" }, { "tabId": 640021, "tabName": "Operator Review" } ], "levels": 
  [ { "permValue": "WEST FS", "permName": "WEST FS" } ] } ], "excluded": [] } ];

const formatted = data.map(c => c.included.map(d => 
  'Included\n\nFor Level ' + d.levelColumnName + 
  '\n\nTabs' + d.tabs.map(e => '\n- ' + e.tabName).join('') + 
  '\n\nPermissions' + d.levels.map(e => '\n- ' + e.permName).join('') )).join('\n');

console.log( formatted );




You are (implicitly) calling String() on an array here:
`Tabs ${d.tabs.map(e => `\n- ` 
+ e.tabName.toString().split(",").join("\n \n"))}`

Your real data does not have a comma in it, so split does nothing. The result of map is an array with three items: ['\n- Growth', '\n- Direct Sales', '\n- Operator Review']. `${array}` is equivalent to String(array), which calls String() on all array items and finally joins the result with a comma, resulting in '\n- Growth,\n- Direct Sales,\n- Operator Review'.
Instead, you want to join the array's items with line breaks and then interpolate the resulting string:
`Tabs\n${d.tabs.map(e => `- ${e.tabName}`).join('\n')}`

It's also a bit odd that you keep mixing template literals with string concatenation. Note that template literals can span multiple lines and include literal line breaks. Functions can help a lot as well to keep your code readable and extensible:


const data = [
  {
    "id": 654298,
    "included": [
      {
        "id": 654298,
        "levelColumn": "DIM4_COL5",
        "levelColumnName": "Region",
        "isIncluded": true,
        "tabs": [
          { "tabId": 640111, "tabName": "Growth" },
          { "tabId": 640031, "tabName": "Direct Sales" },
          { "tabId": 640021, "tabName": "Operator Review" }
        ],
        "levels": [
          { "permValue": "WEST FS", "permName": "WEST FS" }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "excluded": []
  }
];

const toLines = arr => arr.join('\n');
const formatTabs = tabs => tabs.map(e => `- ${e.tabName}`);
const formatLevels = levels => levels.map(e => `- ${e.permName}`);
const formatIncluded = included => included.map(d => `
For Level ${d.levelColumnName}

Tabs
${toLines(formatTabs(d.tabs))}

Permissions
${toLines(formatLevels(d.levels))}`);

const formatted = `Included
${toLines(data.map(c => toLines(formatIncluded(c.included))))}`;

console.log(formatted);



